# Laravel: Cronjob is not working on Windows Amazon EC2 server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Im trying to make a task scheduling on our Amazon EC2 server

I created a basic task in task scheduler. I followed the instructions with this link https://fitdevops.in/how-to-schedule-tasks-in-windows-ec2-instances-or-windows-servers/

In the instructions, they say create a test.bat where the content of my test.bat is this

It will backup the database daily.

```
$file_name = "backup_".strtotime(now()).".sql";
    $command = "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.31/bin/mysqldump.exe --user=".env('DB_USERNAME')." --password=".env('DB_PASSWORD')." --host=".env('DB_HOST')." --port=".env('DB_PORT')." ".env('DB_DATABASE')." > ".storage_path()."/app/public/backup/".$file_name ;
    exec($command);


 /C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/php /C:/wamp64/www/xxx/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Task scheduler**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also, be careful of timezones. See: [Scheduled Task Trigger - Synchronize Across Time Zones · The CLI Guy](https://www.thecliguy.co.uk/2020/02/09/scheduled-task-trigger-synchronize-across-time-zones/)

Comment: What I mean in not working, it didn't create a .sql file in my directory. Does the content of my test.bat correct?

Comment: The Task Scheduler is showing "The task has not yet run". Therefore, you should concentrate on getting the task to trigger. Wait 24 hours and see if it changes, then note the time that it shows. That should give you a hint as to what is happening.

Comment: Im experimenting now, tried to set the time for example 2 minutes from now(11:54am) but it didnt create a file

Comment: What is your "Synchronize across time zones" setting? (See link in my earlier comment)